# Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF. (using \frac{}{} in Section title}

Tags: pdftex, hyperref, packages, mathspec

I am having warning issue as below:

[image]

I know is because of `hyperref`. 
I tried:

```
\section{text \texorpdfstring{{$J = \frac{1}{2}$}}}
```

Original is:

```
 \section{text {$J = \frac{1}{2}$}}
```

But is not working, it give:

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{text {$J = \frac{1}{2}$}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\texorpdfstring` has two arguments, one for the print (tex) and the other for the bookmark (pdf): `tex or pdf string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the following

```
\section{text \texorpdfstring{$J = \frac{1}{2}$}{TEXT}{}}
```